# How to check if the property of an element in an array fetched from the API is equal to certain value using Chai?

Tags: javascript, chai

I have a validation function using `expect`assertions that checks different form fields (checking things such as if the field is empty or not). If an error is catched, an error message indicating which field's assertion failed will be shown. This is working fine.

However I haven't been able to check if the property of an element in an array is equal to certain value. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
function validateNameAndToken (campaign) {
  let campaignName = campaign.name;

  try {
    expect(campaign.name, 'Campaign name can not be empty').to.not.be.empty

    // More expect assertions that are more or less similar


    // This is the assertion that should somehow check if the array contains 
    // an element with its name property equal to campaignName
    expect(API.campaigns, 'The campaign name can not be repeated').to.not.be.an('array').that.includes(campaign);

  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('Campaign#validateNameAndToken - catch: ', err)
    return { isValid: false, msg: err.message }
  }
  return { isValid: true }
}
```

I've seen Chai's docs and I see how to check if an array contains an element, and to see if an object contains a property... But haven't been able to put all pieces together...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use .deep(). Check out the [docs](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep). Hope this helps.

Comment: Also there is .to.have.property()

Comment: something like this? 

    for (let i=0; i<API.campaigns.length; i++) {
      expect(API.campaigns[i].name).to.not.deep.equal(campaignName);
    }

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I've been away. That should do what you expect. I ran something similar just a moment ago against two mismatching objects.